# MVC - How should components inside controller communicate?

Tags: java, design-patterns, mvc

I'm developing a level editor in Java. I'm designing its code in MVC. From what I've learned: controllers can have a direct reference (fields) to views and models. Views can have direct reference to models but shouldn't have to controllers (they can interact controllers via design patterns such as observers) and models shouldn't have any direct references to any views or controllers (also should use observer). My question is: How should controllers interact each other? Two-way references is not recommended AFAIK, so how should they interact each other? This question can also be relevant between viewers.
Thanks

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [Is a good practice to call a Controller function from another Controller?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/264402/31260)

Comment: Controllers should generally focus on all the logic it requires, and, if necessary, reuses utility classes or derives from a base class for any and all shared logic.  Direct communication between controllers is generally discouraged, though if you must, you should probably consider using events rather than direct calls.

Comment: "controllers can have a direct reference (fields) to viewers" - really? Isn't the controller supposed to not know anything about the view?

Comment: @FrankPuffer afaik yes, it can have a direct access. Like this example from wikipedia: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/ModelViewControllerDiagram2.svg

Comment: how about https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/316931/is-there-a-good-formal-pattern-to-manage-state-in-mvvm/316958#316958